# Make a single SSH connection via paramiko and send a command to check the hostname and a 2nd command to see if there is anything in the www directory

Tags: python, linux, ssh

Your manager just asked you to find out what is the hostname (/etc/hostname) and if there are any files in the www directory. Your manager wants you to check this on two Ubuntu-based machines. However, they want you to have this written in a way that will scale to all 100 servers on the network. Achieve the following items:

Make a Flowchart.

Create Pseudocode.

Make a single SSH connection via paramiko and send a command to check the hostname and a second command to see if there is anything in the www directory.

Input the IP addresses from a file (text or CSV).

Save the output of both commands, make sure to note what IP the data came from, to a file (text or CSV).

Comment: This is just a set of requirements. What is your actual question?

Answer (score 0):

As mirlinda said, this is a set of requirement rather than a question. I just have a plan for your information.

1. You can write all ip address to text file with one ip per line.
2. Use `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your mail"` command to create ssh rsa key in your 100 servers.
3. Run `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub root@[ip]` to make your administrator machine can access which server you want to access without password.
4. Write a python script to read one ip per time from the text file saved your all server ip by `readline` interface.
5. And use `check_output` interface to run `hostname` command to get server host name and `ls [full path of www]` to get contents of www directory.
6. You just can save return contents of `check_output` interface to a file by redirection symbol '>'.
7. Loop operations 4-6 in your python script by using while or for statement until get all host name and contents of www of all 100 servers.